# Under which conditions do the restriction maps of sheaves of modules occur to be injective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a scheme which is at least integral. Further let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Now under which conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ and/or $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ do we obtain that the restriction maps

$$\rho_{U \subseteq V}: \mathcal{F}(V) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(U)$$ 
for open subsets $U \subseteq V$ of $X$ are injective?

In the case $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_X$ we need that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is integral (hence the above assumption) which proves that such sheaves indeed exist. Are we able to classify such sheaves by certain conditions? Maybe some property like quasi-coherence or $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules which are embedded in the function field of $X$.

I'll be grateful for any kind of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case when $X$ is affine, $X=Spec(A)$ and $M$ is a coherent module, that is an $A$-module, the question is equivalent to the following:
Let $f\in A$, and $g:M\rightarrow M_f$ the canonical map, where $M_f$ is the localization of $M$, is $g$ injective ? This is true if $M$ does not have torsion.

Comment: At which point do you need that $M$ is a coherent $A$-module? Beside that: Thus we may say that torsion-free coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module satisfy the desired property?

Comment: Certainly quasi-coherent is enough, yes, torsion free sheaves satisfy this property.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is annoying, but: 'torsion free **quasi-coherent** sheaves' satisfy this property, right?

Comment: If I use the definition of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{F} = \tilde{M}$ on the affine patch $X=Spec(A)$, I don't use torsion-freeness: Let $V \subset U$ be two open subsets in $X$. and let $h:U \rightarrow \coprod_{P \in U}$ be a **non-zero** section of $\mathcal{F}$ on $U$. Then by definition there exists a point $P \in U$ and open subset $U_P$ s.t. $\forall Q \in U_P: h(Q) = m/f \neq 0$ and $m \in M,\,f \in A\setminus P$. Since $U_P$ is open there is a nontrivial intersection with $V$ and thus the restriction of $h$ to $V$ cannot be the zero section. Where did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answer, this is how you reduce to the affine case:

Let $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ be an affine open cover, $V \subset X$ any open subset and $f \in \mathcal F(X)$ with $f_{|V}=0$. For the sake of notation let $V_i := U_i \cap V$.

In particular $f_{|V_i}=0$ for all $i$. By the result in the affine case, we have an injection $\mathcal F(U_i) \to \mathcal F(V_i)$, hence $f_{|U_i}=0$ for all $i$. The sheaf properties yield $f=0$, the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

See the following picture from my personal notes. For integral scheme $X$ and quasi-coherent modules $\mathcal{F}$ (so we can check this in the algebra setting),

> the restriction maps are injective if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is
> torsion free.

In this case we also have a nice characterization of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ for any non-empty open $U$ (not just affine open),
$$\mathcal{F}(U)=\bigcap_{p\in U}\mathcal{F}_p$$
[image: picture 1]
[image]